# How to Integrate dynamic URL in angular dropzone directive

Tags: angularjs, dropzone.js

I am using 
https://github.com/vberbenetz/EasyUpload code for file upload in angularjs.
Here are link of angular dropzone --[dropzone](http://www.cantangosolutions.com/blog/Easy-File-Upload-Using-DropzoneJS-AngularJs-And-Spring.)

I want to uploaded file for multiple path. how to configure drozone directive for dynamic url
Here is Drop-zone directive

```
appControllers.directive('dropzone', dropzone);
function dropzone(){
return function(scope, element, attrs) {


    var config = {
        url : "api/company/logo/1",--->i want this url dynamically
        maxFilesize: 100,
        paramName: "uploadfile",
        maxThumbnailFilesize: 10,
        parallelUploads: 1,
        autoProcessQueue: true
    };

    var eventHandlers = {
        'addedfile': function(file) {           
            scope.file = file;
            if (this.files[1]!=null) {
                this.removeFile(this.files[0]);
            }
            scope.$apply(function() {
                scope.fileAdded = true;
            });
        },

        'success': function (file, response) {
        }
    };

    dropzone = new Dropzone(element[0], config);

    angular.forEach(eventHandlers, function(handler, event) {
        dropzone.on(event, handler);
    });


    scope.processDropzone = function() {
        dropzone.processQueue();
    };

    scope.resetDropzone = function() {
        dropzone.removeAllFiles();
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

directive code:

```
    scope.processDropzone = function(url) {
        dropzone.options.url = url;
        dropzone.processQueue();
    };
```

and from controller:

```
    $scope.processDropzone("http://localhost:8080/my/custom/upload");
```